# How to check the event received in Azure Event Hub

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Perhaps a rather simple question, yet I couldn't find the answers after doing some searching.

After I have send an event to an Azure event Hub (via the Java code), how could I check back in the Azure Portal about the event that I have sent ?
(so that I could inspect the header and body of the event content for verification).

In the Azure Portal, after I have clicked in the event hub, there is a metric to show the incoming requests, but this only shows the counts, but I would want to inspect the individual event recevied.

Comment: You can refer to [Use Java to receive events from Azure Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-send#receive-events) and [Sending and Receiving Events from Azure Event Hub](https://www.reddit.com/r/AZURE/comments/phc1l3/sending_and_receiving_events_from_azure_event_hub/)

Answer (score 3):

You can inspect the data on the portal with Azure Stream Analytics test consumer which can be loaded on the entity blade.

[image]

Comment: Is there a cost consideration with that approach, Serkant?  Does it spin up an ASA resource?

Comment: I'm getting the message: "There is no data from input 'myhub'. Please make sure the input source has data and then try again." when I try that

Comment: You can view the data. There is an extra step after creating a Stream Analytics job. It will consume from your EventHub and you can Query this from the Stream Analytics job.

To do so, navigate to the actual Azure Page for the Stream Analytics Job. This can be done by selecting it from your Resource Group or from your EventHub -> Process Data -> Stream Analytics jobs -> Open metrics. Then, click Query in the left-hand blade, select the Time Range you'd like to pull data from, and run the query. Your events (1-day retention) will show up.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, it's not currently possible to inspect Event Hubs events via the portal.  To do you, you'd either need to read the events using one of the SDKs or a product like [Service Bus Explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer) to inspect them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to your question is Azure Monitor. Check out [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/monitor-event-hubs-reference) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found this VS code extension pretty handy to view the events in the Azure Event hub.

VS Code extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Summer.azure-event-hub-explorer

This is a terminal based approach, and might work only for development workloads (since the events flow could be higher in other environments).